# How can I get the list of Typescript files that tsc will compile?

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript2.9

I'm trying to write a `grunt` task in a Typescript project to measure some statistics of the source files. To do that, I have a function that takes a single source file, runs `typescript.createSourceFile` from it, and does some stuff to the returned AST. The problem is finding all the files to iterate over: I'd like to get exactly the same list of files that `tsc -p tsconfig.json` will compile later. The intention is to filter out some files from that list and then iterate over the filtered list.

I imagine I'd use the `typescript` module to do this, but I can't find a function to do it. I found [the place in the `tsc` source that turns tsconfig into a list of files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ece46113a57313be331554806ccdfdbef4d4395e/src/tsc/tsc.ts#L134), and it seems to be using a function that's not exported.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
tsc --listFiles --noEmit
```

This will list the files that tsc will compile based on the `tsconfig.json` it uses.

Answer (score 8):

I think you want the `--listFilesOnly` flag.

> Print names of files that are part of the compilation and then stop processing.

Example:

```
tsc --listFilesOnly path/to/tsconfig.json
```

[TypeScript Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options)

Comment: Note: the tsconfig should be preceded by `-p`: `tsc --listFilesOnly -p path/to/tsconfig.json`